Playing .lottie files in React Native
Using expo51 and react native.74 I am unable to play .lottie files using the lottie-react-native package.
Following the documentation for lottie animations, I am able to play my lottie animations with json files. But when I try .lottie files, it doesn't display, even after following the documentation
text
I have read that the documentation on the metro config is not up to date, as a probable cause.

me too facing the same issue
